# HTML to PDF in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pdf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

In an ASP.NET project I need to generate a PDF for the user to download which is made from HTML. That HTML has img's in it too, which need to be embedded. It would also be great if links are clickable.

Now i've tried a whole range of different product demo's, and they all either don't work, are classic ASP, or are horridly expensive.

This is for a commercial application.

The most promising (although expensive) looked like http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm but the example code from HTML to PDF (found here: http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8net/source/5-abcpdf6/doc/1-methods/addimagetochain.htm)crashes IIS, on every page I try, with a very generic error message.

Please can someone suggest a product for this. I can't run an CMD line app on the server unfortunately, so it does have to be just a dll that I stick in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically create a PDF in my .NET application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application)

Comment: I was just searching for this as well.  All of the SO answers show iTextSharp with the most votes but it recently changed to GPL from MIT meaning it is no longer applicable for some of us.

Comment: Yeah, iTextSharp is $2000 for commercial purposes :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague found Evo PDF, http://www.evopdf.com/. We've used it successfully to generate PDFs from HTML, with images, clickable links, and a multitude of other features. I think that it uses the Webkit rendering engine. It's a .NET library that sits on your server. Very easy to use and excellent reproduction.

Comment: Although this is one of the more expensive ones, it is perfect for what we need, and works great. Thanks!

Comment: As an end user I tried opening a PDF made by EvoPDF and it crashed Safari and Preview on OS X, something I've never seen before, so do double-check the PDFs you make don't do the same!

Answer (score 0):

This looks promissing: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfizer/
Not from personal experience, but I see some recommendations, and best of all - it's free :)
And a code example:
http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/c-free-component-generate-pdf-convert-html-pdf

Comment: Unfortunately that relies on iText which has commercial licensing. I have inquired about pricing, and am still waiting for a response.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally worked on [this product](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/convert-sharepoint-html-pages-to-pdf.html), which has been optimised for server based environments and works via a web services based interface. It can convert other formats as well and includes a strong watermarking and PDF Security engine.

Comment: You are that company are you not? Due to security, everything must be done on our server though.

Comment: You would install this product on your server. It is not a hosted service (Yes, I represent that company as I mentioned)